# Numpy: understanding broadcasting rules

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder why `c` shape in this example becomes `(4, 4, 4)` ? How broadcasting rules working in this case?

```
a = np.ones((4,4))
b = np.ones((4,4,1))*2
c = np.multiply(a,b)

a.shape
(4, 4)
b.shape
(4, 4, 1)
c.shape
(4, 4, 4)
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)? Nothing particularly unusual is going on here.

Comment: Two 4x4 *planes* at right angles. Figure 6 at https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc

Comment: 1st step is to match the number of dimensions, `a` becomes (1,4,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.shape
(4, 4)
b.shape
(4, 4, 1)
```

`broadcasting` first adjusts the number of dimensions.  It can only add leading dimensions, hence `a` becomes (1, 4, 4) shape.  This 'leading' rule avoids ambiguity.

The 2nd step is to adjust size 1 dimensions to match:

```
(1, 4, 4) and (4, 4, 1) => (4, 4, 4)

c.shape
(4, 4, 4)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your *a* is a list with 4 nested arrays, and inside each nested array it has 4 lists.

Your *b* is a list with 4 nested arrays, and inside each nested array it has 4 nested lists and each nested list has only 1 value.

Now ".multiply", multiplies each value in 4 nested lists of *b* by each of 4 lists of *a*.

Hence the result *c* has the shape (4,4,4) which means: a list with 4 nested arrays and inside each nested array it has 4 lists and each list has 4 values!

This is how broadcasting adjusts the different shapes of arrays to apply the operations.

Comment: `a` is one `numpy` array with shape (4,4).  Talking about 'nested arrays' doesn't help.  This doesn't explain `numpy` `broadcasting`.

Comment: @hpaulj yes you are right nested arrays does not explain broadcasting. As he was asking about how this shape is changed by broadcasting I was trying to explain how this shape adjusting works.  As documents already say this processes. I'm happy that your explanations has been useful for him. Regarding your useful comment I edited my answer. Thanks.